# geospatial query for point within multipolygon?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

The AWS DynamoDB [Geospatial library](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-geo) documentation lists the following query options:

- **Box Queries:** Return all of the items that fall within a pair of geo points that define a rectangle as projected onto a sphere.
- **Radius Queries:** Return all of the items that are within a given radius of a geo point.

Is it possible to do more advanced queries such as searching for items that fall within a [Polygon](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#id4) or [MultiPolygon](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#id7)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't believe the current library supports more advanced queries. Feel free to open feature request issues on github and the DynamoDB team will look into it putting it on the roadmap in the future.